# Find the value of $\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{x \rightarrow 2 \\ y \rightarrow 1}} \frac{\arcsin(xy-2)}{\arctan(3xy-6)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Do I have to use some trigonometrical formulas, or in which way can I start to solve the problem?

Comment: will it be simple 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arctan x}x=1$$

we can do

$$\frac{\arctan(xy-2)}{\arctan(3xy-6)}=\frac13\frac{\arctan(xy-2)}{xy-2}\cdot\frac{3xy-6}{\arctan(3xy-6)}\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(2,1)]{}\frac13\cdot1\cdot1=\frac13$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=\arcsin(xy-2) \\\ $

So $\sin(z)=xy-2 \\$

Multiply both sides by 3 gives: $3 \sin(z)=3xy-6$

So we can write the limit as

$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{z}{\arctan(3 \sin(z))}$

This might be more familiar looking to evaluate.
Using L'hospital gets you the answer after one round.

Answer (score 1):

*Shorter with equivalents:*

$\arcsin u\sim_0 u$, $\;\arctan u\sim_0 u$, so
$\;\dfrac{\arcsin(xy-2)}{\arctan(3xy-6)}\sim_0 \dfrac{xy-2}{3xy-6}=\dfrac13.$